# Stochastic value obtained from pine script not matching with actual value in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, stochastic

I am trying to plot stochastic (14,1,1) in trading view using pine script. But I if I plot the stochastics indicator using the indicators tool of trading view, the output is different.I am using the code as below:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
Length = input (14, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k = input (1, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
d = input (1, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %D")
Sto = stoch (close, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
K= sma (Sto, k)
D= sma (Sto, d)
plot (D, title  ="%D", color = color.red, linewidth=1)
plot (K, title  ="%K", color = color.aqua, linewidth=1)
hline(80, title = "Upper Limit", color = color.red, linestyle =  hline.style_dotted)
hline(20, title = "Lower Limit", color = color.lime, linestyle =  hline.style_dotted)
```

[Screenshot of stochastics in tradingview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dtqH.png)

The difference can be seen in the above screenshot.

Pls help in correcting the code if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use:

```
Sto = stoch (close, high, low, Length)
```

instead of:

```
Sto = stoch (close, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

In 5 version of Pine script

```
//@version=5
indicator("lk - Stoch (v5)")

//Input values for configuration on the chart
Length = input.int (defval=14, title = "Stochastic Length", minval=1, step=1)
k = input.int (defval=3, title = "Stochastic %K", minval=1, step=1)
d = input.int (defval=3, title = "Stochastic %D", minval=1, step=1)


Sto = ta.stoch (close, high, low, Length)
K= ta.sma (Sto, k)
D= ta.sma (Sto, d)

//Drawing 
plot (D, title  ="%D", color = color.green, linewidth=1)
plot (K, title  ="%K", color = color.lime, linewidth=1)
hline(80, title = "Upper Limit", color = color.red, linestyle =  hline.style_dotted)
hline(20, title = "Lower Limit", color = color.lime, linestyle =  hline.style_dotted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to work out highest and lowest first

```
length = input.int (defval=14, title = "Stochastic Length", minval=1, step=1)
smoothD = input.int (defval=5, title = "Stochastic %D", minval=1, step=1)

highest = ta.highest(high, length)
// lowest low
lowest = ta.lowest(low, length)

k = ta.stoch (close, highest, lowest, length)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
```